# Pig:Relation and Schema name confusion

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

In Pig Latin;this works as expected:

```
filtered = FILTER records BY age > 27;
```

But this throws an exception (when >>  DUMP filtered):

```
filtered = FILTER records BY records.age > 27;
```

This is the excepiton:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (John,Wilk,27,M), 2nd :(Tri,Tim,27,F)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (John,Wilk,27,M), 2nd :(Tri,Tim,27,F)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.ReadScalars.exec(ReadScalars.java:119)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:345)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextInteger(POUserFunc.java:394)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:322)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.GreaterThanExpr.getNextBoolean(GreaterThanExpr.java:74)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POFilter.getNextTuple(POFilter.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:282)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:277)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What is the difference between the two? Are not they same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, both the stmts are different.

1. First stmt is perfectly valid, in this case, pig will iterate through each row and apply the filter constraint(age > 27). Its a standard way of using filter stmts.
2. In the second case, you used `dereference operator(.)` to access the fields, but the dereference operator are mainly used to access the complex data types(Tuples,Bags and Maps) values, when you use dereference operator to access the fields then pig will `always expect the scalar output`(ie, only one output after the filter condition) unfortunately your filter condition(age > 27) return `more than one matching result`, that is the reason you got "`Scalar has more than one row in the output`"
   In case your filter condition(age>27) return only one output then your stmt is perfectly valid.